# Standalone web apps using Firefox on Android

Tags: android, firefox, progressive-web-apps

So I've added a very basic manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Myname",
    "start_url": "/mobile/activities",
    "display": "standalone",
    "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

Adding this to the homescreen using Chrome works as expected: when opening the new icon the website opens in a standalone browser.

When I do the same with Firefox, however, it does not. It just opens in the browser.

By reading the docs I get the impression Firefox supports the "display: standalone" setting. Is this some leftover documentation from the Firefox OS days? Am I doing something wrong or is this just not supported?

Answer (score 1):

I have also just come up against this. Eventually found this to be a known bug with Firfox for Android:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1285858